# does Job instance takes a list of jobs in constructor in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, jobs, hadoop2

[Here](https://github.com/tomwhite/hadoop-book/blob/master/ch16/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/programs/labs/trackstats/TrackStatisticsProgram.java) is the snippet of code from Hadoop: The definitive guide book;

```
    ArrayList<Job> mergeDependencies = new ArrayList<Job>();
    mergeDependencies.add(listenersJob);
    mergeDependencies.add(sumJob);
    JobConf mergeConf = getMergeConf(outputDir, sumOutputDir, listenersOutputDir);
    Job mergeJob = new Job(mergeConf, mergeDependencies);
```

As you can notice, the `constructor` for `Job` takes a list of `jobs`. I went through the [documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html) for `Job Class`. I could not see any such constructors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code snippet you are using is referring org.apache.hadoop.mapred.jobcontrol.job class not mapreduce job that you are looking at, check out [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/jobcontrol/Job.html)